# Open source RTSP streaming server

Tags: linux, rtsp

I want to stream videos to mobile phones in RTSP format. I want to set up an RTSP server. Is there any CDN that suppport RTSP or should I set up a VPS and go for an RTSP server. If so what is the suggested Open source server.

Must Support 3gp streaming to mobile.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLC streaming server - http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/

Another would be Darwin Streaming Server - http://dss.macosforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

Red5 is an open-source java-based streamingserver for flash.

http://www.red5.org/